# Avalability in Microservices architecture

Tags: architecture, microservices, high-availability

I am learning to migrate a legacy(monolithic)based architecture to micro services architect. What techniques can I use to ensure availability of the system? How can I implement in the architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Microservices is a very broad topic, for architecture questions I suggest you read e.g. [Building Microservices](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/building-microservices/9781491950340/) by Sam Newman and/or [Production-Ready Microservices](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920053675.do) by Susan Fowler to learn more about them.

Answering a question "How to make sure my whole solution doesn't go down when service is not available?" (which I assume is what you are looking for) on a space ship level - you have two options:

1. Retries when service you depend on fails - this is how Netflix does
   it, you can do it manually, or if you are on Java stack, e.g.
   [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix)
2. Queues for communication between services preferably PaaS queue systems (AWS SQS, Azure ServiceBus), since managing highly available queue platform is a challenge on its own.

If this isn't the question you have on your mind, please be more specific :) Or read mentioned books first, they should answer many initial questions (or at least make you aware of potential challenges) in the microservices space.

Comment: What about the circuit pattern? Is it also something for avalability @Lech Migdal

Comment: Good point, circuit breaker is one of the nice things that Hystrix gives you out of the box :) @user3877872

Comment: https://ibb.co/f2uhPv have made the simple architecture with three services , how can reflect the the circuit breaker in my architecture. And I have also added the queue for asynchronous calls to ensure performance. Do all three services need to be connected the same queue? Would that enhance performance? And how can reflect the circuit breaker in the architecture and retries as you mentioned before? @Lech Migdal

Comment: Honestly, I would suggest two reads, a more generic, talking also about using queues - https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/microservices-on-aws.pdf and circuit breaker specific  https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html. Queue will not actually improve performance, but help with availability (and potentially scaling out consumers based on the queue size). As for putting circuit breaker on architecture diagram, this is in my eyes more of an implementation details, so I would put it as a note to a connection only. Specific details of fallback/retries/fail behavior can be nailed later.

Comment: So the queues need to be used between all microservices like account, inventory, shipping? Or only account and inventory needs to be connected with the queue? And why?@Lech Migdal

Comment: It all depends on your requirements :) In general, if you can, from availability pov, all communication between services should be performed asynchronously, in the backend e.g. through a queuing solution.